# Restrict nested data in result of search

Tags: elasticsearch

Have an index that stores tasks to do, in it there is a user id, task id and inside there is nested data that is used to store a timer that the user started and finished working on a task.

I have a script that I used in Elasticsearch 6 that searched for tasks and timers in a specific period, and the script only returned timers that matched that time.

However, I recently migrated to Elasticsearch 8 and the script doesn't work like before, now it returns all tasks that have a timer in the period, but I don't restrict it to just the timers in that period.

The tasks are returned correctly, but so are all the timers within it.

How can I make the script return only timers that match the filter?

Script:

```
{
    "size": 1024,
    "track_total_hits": true,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "user_id": 123
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "timer.content",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": {
                                    "range": {
                                        "timer.content.start_work": {
                                            "gte": "2023-08-26T00:00:00-0300",
                                            "lte": "2023-09-26T23:59:59-0300"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "user_status": [
                            "E",
                            "I"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "task_id": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    },
    "_source": []
}
```

Index Structure:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "ignoreaccents": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "task_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "user_id": {
                "type": "long",
                "index": true
            },
            "user_status": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "index": true
            },
            "timer": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "content": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "timer_id": {
                                "type": "long",
                                "index": true
                            },
                            "task_id": {
                                "type": "long",
                                "index": true
                            },
                            "user_id": {
                                "type": "long",
                                "index": true
                            },
                            "start_work": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "index": true,
                                "format": "strict_date_time_no_millis"
                            },
                            "end_work": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "index": true,
                                "format": "strict_date_time_no_millis"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.10/inner-hits.html) to the nested query, you can also optionally exclude time.content using [`excludes` in the `_source` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-search-api-query-params) option. Here an example:

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "ignoreaccents": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "task_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "user_id": {
                "type": "long",
                "index": true
            },
            "user_status": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "index": true
            },
            "timer": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "content": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "timer_id": {
                                "type": "long",
                                "index": true
                            },
                            "task_id": {
                                "type": "long",
                                "index": true
                            },
                            "user_id": {
                                "type": "long",
                                "index": true
                            },
                            "start_work": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "index": true,
                                "format": "strict_date_time_no_millis"
                            },
                            "end_work": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "index": true,
                                "format": "strict_date_time_no_millis"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT test/_bulk?refresh
{"index": {}}
{"user_id": 123, "user_status": "E", "timer": {"content": [{"timer_id": 1, "start_work": "2023-06-01T00:00:00-0300"}, {"timer_id": 2, "start_work": "2023-09-01T00:00:00-0300"} ]}}

GET test/_search
{
  "size": 1024,
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": 123
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "timer.content",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": {
                  "range": {
                    "timer.content.start_work": {
                      "gte": "2023-08-26T00:00:00-0300",
                      "lte": "2023-09-26T23:59:59-0300"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "user_status": [
              "E",
              "I"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "task_id": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "excludes": "timer.content"
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you have an example of the query in inner_hits?

We tried several ways to place the query inside it and nothing worked.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Thank you very much.
It helped us a lot.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer as a solution then?

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot.
Answer accepted :D
Thank you again.